# Pandas column taking very long time to translate

Tags: python, pandas, google-translation-api

I have a pandas dataframe of some 200k records. It has two columns; the text in English and a score. I want to translate a column from English to a few other languages. For that, I'm using the Cloud Translation API from Google's GCP. It's however, taking an absurdly long time to translate them. My code is basically this:

```
def translate_text(text, target_language):
    from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
    try:
        translate_client = translate.Client(credentials=credentials)
        result = translate_client.translate(text, target_language=target_language)
        return result['translatedText'] 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

and this:

```
df['X_language'] = df['text'].apply(lambda text: translate_text(text, '<LANG CODE>'))
```

I've seen that `apply()` is fairly slow, plus the response from the API might be another factor in it being slow, but is there any way to make it more efficient? I tried swifter but that barely shaved off a couple of seconds (when testing against a subset of the dataframe).

Note that some of the text fields in the dataframe have around 300 characters in them. Not many but a decent number.

**EDIT**:

After importing `translate` from `google.cloud` and defining the client once outside the function, the code ran much quicker. However, for some reason when I try to pass a list (the rows of the 'text' column), it doesn't return the translated text; it just runs quickly and returns the list itself in English.

Might that have to do with the credentials I'm using, or? I'm passing the service account JSON file you get when you create a project in GCP.

**EDIT 2**:

I partitioned my dataframe into 4, each with ~50k records. It still takes too much time. I even removed all text with more than 250 characters..

I think it's an translation API issue? It takes way too long to translate I guess.

Comment: Import the module and create the client one time outside of the function. You can call [`translate`](https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/2.0.1/usage.html)(look at the last example) with a `list` of phrases or words.

Comment: First suggestion shaved off a good 60% of the time. I tried converting the column into a list (called .values() on it then to a list and also directly to a list), but when I put it through the function, it returns the same text column not the translated one for some reason. I tried with a subset of the list and same result.

Comment: I tried passing a list and I was able to get the translated values. Can you edit the question to show your updated code that uses list as input?

Comment: I believe the issue is because I somehow reached request or character user limits? I didn't use it much and I thought I had 6 million characters per minute per project and over 6k requests per minute. I'm using v2.

Comment: You might have hit the [recommended maximum length for each request](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas#content) which is 5k characters. Can you try splitting your request into multiple request?

Comment: But if you really need to translate in one request, I suggest to use [translate by batch](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/batch-translation).

Comment: So, I did have a couple of hundred text with over 5k characters and over 2000 text with 2k and above characters. I dropped the rows but got the same error - `403 POST https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?prettyPrint=false: User Rate Limit Exceeded`. I tried splitting my request into multiple by taking subsets of the dataframe but same thing. I'll try by batch.

Comment: Did the translate by batch work? Also it seems that you really breached the [per minute quota](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas) as per `User Rate Limit Exceeded` error.

Comment: I had to created another GCP account. When I saw the quotas in the old account (trial), nothing was exceeded or close to, but the trial period apparently ended and I didn't have the $400 dollars anymore. I tried enabling billing for the API (and checked my card wasn't defunct) but that didn't change much. Translate by batch worked very well in my newer account.

Comment: @CallumMatthews you can post this as an answer and accept it, so the solution is visible and will help the others who encounter this problem in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the slow code, I just initialized the import and translate client outside the function once.

In the case of the 403 POST error, I had to create another GCP account. When I saw the quotas in the old account (trial), nothing was exceeded or close to, but the trial period apparently ended and I didn't have the free credits ($400) anymore. I tried enabling billing for the API (and checked my card wasn't defunct) but that didn't change much. Translate by batch worked in my newer account.

So, it was just an account issue rather than an API issue.